# Unattended 22.04 desktop remote access - how

Tags: ssh, vnc

I have a fresh 22.04 install laptop sitting on a shelf unattended.
SSH server is installed.
VNC also came along with the install.
These servers are running, NETSTAT shows their listeners active

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22    0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
> tcp6       0      0 :::5900       :::*      LISTEN

I can approve SSH and Remote Desktop(VNC) from the settings/sharing menu
But
Both **require** me to have a local login active on this laptop, AND I have to accept an incoming VNC request on this local login.

- I want this laptop to respond to SSH login as I would expect from a
  proper Linux host
- I want this laptop to allow VNC sessions without
  intervention on the local desktop

VNC does not have to be installed
SSH is already installed
**I should NOT have to use SSH to vnc into the laptop**

Apparently some setting forces the OS to require local GUI active to allow both SSH and VNC access.

My single question is how do I override the requirement to have a local GUI session active to allow both SSH and VNC access?

Thanks
Leo

Comment: There is no single config file. An SSH server and VNC server must both be installed. SSH and VNC server (or RDP or x2Go) configs must be set up. An SSH key should be exchanged for basic security. If using VNC, an SSH tunnel should be set up for basic security. Then you are ready to begin remote desktop logins. It's unclear which element or config you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. Yes, it says I did in the first line of the note

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1438063/edit) your original question to add information or clarifications. Comments are how we try to help you make your question clear and answerable. Comments are not intended for conversation.